# Time out selenium in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This is my code to download Github archive events from gharchive. These events are aggregated into hourly archives. I have used Selenium to access and download these events but I got Time out error during the downloading process. My code succeeded in opening Chrome and downloading the first 4 files. At the time reaching the fifth file, it got time out
I used:
Selenium 3.141.59
chromedriver 91.0.4472.101
Chrome 91.0.4472.124
java 1.8.0_291

I just don't know why it got an error. Please help me.

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:/Users/Asus Zenbook/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/win32/91.0.4472.101/chromedriver.exe");

    Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    prefs.put("download.default_directory", "D:\\Selenium");

    DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
    options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
    caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
    
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();        
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
        driver.get("https://data.gharchive.org/" + startDate + "-" + i + ".json.gz");
    }
```

```
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`
Starting ChromeDriver 91.0.4472.101 (af52a90bf87030dd1523486a1cd3ae25c5d76c9b-refs/branch-heads/4472@{#1462}) on port 3061
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Jul 11, 2021 5:29:48 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
[1625999692.850][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000
[1625999692.851][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.007
[1625999692.864][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.007
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.007
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.124)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-IQKFBUD7', ip: '192.168.100.7', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '15.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 91.0.4472.124, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 91.0.4472.101 (af52a90bf870..., userDataDir: C:\Users\ASUSZE~1\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:60130}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: d386753170869015e6092d7f0cfe37f2
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:277)
    at selenium.TestSelenium.downloadFileInDateRange(TestSelenium.java:71)
    at selenium.TestSelenium.main(TestSelenium.java:120)
```

Comment: What is `startDate` ?

Comment: what is version of Java do you use? The version you mentioned  `1.8.0_291` but the system info shows `15.0.1`

Comment: startDate is a string containing a date like 2021-07-11. The link to download data has a form like https://data.gharchive.org/2021-07-11-1.json.gz such that 1 is the hour. For example, the link I have just mentioned is to download github event at 1am 11th July 2021

Comment: I am sorry, 1.8.0_291 is the version of JDK

Comment: @AnitaHalley Same code is working fine for me. Can you please share the logic behind the `startDate`. How you are dynamically generating it?

Comment: I downloaded data from this link https://www.gharchive.org/ .  Actually, my entire project requirement is to download data on a specified date range. It means my program will need to accept 2 date parameters `startDate` and `endDate`. A sample download link is https://data.gharchive.org/2015-01-01-15.json.gz

Comment: @AnitaHalley Ok but same code is working fine for me. It can be due to internet speed or bandwidth issue. Can you add some delay inside     `for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
        driver.get("https://data.gharchive.org/" + startDate + "-" + i + ".json.gz");
    }`

Comment: Thanks so much. I was really confused cause I could not find the problems in my code. Really appreciate your help